# NSShowNonLocalizedStrings only working on the first string?

Tags: ios, localization

I created a new iOS app in Xcode 5.1.1, targeting iOS 7.1, and added these lines in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
NSLog(@"test1=%@", NSLocalizedString(@"test1", nil));
NSLog(@"test2=%@", NSLocalizedString(@"test2", nil));
```

I added -NSShowNonLocalizedStrings YES to the project's scheme, and when I launch it, it prints:

```
2014-07-21 13:08:05.414 TestProj[64366:60b] Localizable string "test1" not found in strings table "Localizable" of bundle CFBundle 0x8f6e740 </Users/stevex/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/46F07A17-2E4D-4354-96C2-82450592F68D/TestProj.app> (executable, loaded).
2014-07-21 13:08:05.415 TestProj[64366:60b] test1=TEST1
2014-07-21 13:08:05.415 TestProj[64366:60b] test2=test2
```

Only the first string is being processed by NSShowNonLocalizedStrings, which seems incorrect given the documentation I've seen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to apple's [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html), only:

> AppKit–based applications can take advantage of built-in support to detect strings that do not need to be localized and those that need to be localized but currently are not.

As a result, OS X app can use it but iOS app is excluded.

Comment: The heading for the section in the Localization documentation says: [Detecting Non-localized Strings (OS X v10.10 and later)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html). Mac OS X only.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that the NSShowNonLocalizedStrings default doesn't work very well when your app uses the newer "Base" localization system -- is that what you're using?

In Base localization, that argument logs and capitalizes every single string in a XIB even when the localization is present, going as far as to capitalize and log the correctly translated text.  This makes NSShowNonLocalizedStrings largely useless.

I found it easier to use a service like [Babble-On's pseudo-localization](http://www.ibabbleon.com/app_localization.html) to generate bogus translations -- this was much easier to find issues.  If you collect your localization strings with genstrings and then upload to them, they generate a fake translation, say in French, and then you run your app with **-AppleLanguages (fr)** and **-AppleLocale fr_CA**.

That service's pseudo-localization basically accents every character and adds some padding.  As you look through your UI, anything that is actually readable wasn't translated.